# How do I list the members of a group?

Tags: user-management

How can I see all the members of a group in Linux?

Answer (score 226, accepted):

Use the commands:

```
getent group groupname
```

or

```
getent group groupname | awk -F: '{print $4}' |  tr "," " "
```

Comment: So to add group, add user to group, change permissions of folder to group, and get all members of group, you would run the following commands respectively: addgroup programmers
adduser donato programmers
chown -R root:programmers idea-IU-141.1010.3
getent group programmers

Comment: chmod -R g+w idea-IU-141.1010.3

Comment: Interesting find, "getent groups" (without any group specified) and "cat /etc/group" both give exactly the same output, at least on my system.

Comment: This answer is not really complete. `members <group>` probably gives more what the OP is looking for. The difference is explained here [Link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271766/597223)

Comment: I am not sure this works well for non-standard accounts. Try the following two examples: `groups root && getent group root` and `groups lxd && getent group users`. Can anybody shed some light why in above cases _root_ user is not listed as a member of a _root_ group as well as _lxd_ user (you need to have LXD/LXC installed) is not listed as a member of a _users_ group where in fact both have groups assigned to them in _groups_? However `groups pulse && getent group audio` works as expected and _pulse_ user listed as a member of an _audio_ group in both command outputs.

Comment: In addition to my comment above, you will find a mismatch in `getent group groupname` with `compgen -u | xargs -I {} sh -c 'groups {}'` for the following groups: _audio, lp, nogroup, plugdev, users_ on Ubuntu 22 LTS. Is there an explanation for such behaviour?

Answer (score 32):

You can do

```bsh
members YOUR_GROUP_NAME
```

and it will list all the users in the group `YOUR_GROUP_NAME`.

If it's not installed by default:

```bsh
sudo apt-get install members
```

Comment: where did you find such command?

Comment: You may need to install it `sudo apt-get install members`

Comment: members is installed by default in Ubuntu 14.04.5

Comment: it was not installed by default in 20.04 Desktop LTS, even after a successful smb and cif-utils installation

Answer (score 20):

One more way to check all the members of a group is by checking the `/etc/group` file which lists all the groups and its members

Example:

```
root:x:0:
daemon:x:1:
bin:x:2:
sys:x:3:
adm:x:4:syslog,nikhil
tty:x:5:
disk:x:6:
lp:x:7:
mail:x:8:
news:x:9:
uucp:x:10:
man:x:12:
proxy:x:13:
kmem:x:15:
dialout:x:20:
fax:x:21:
voice:x:22:
cdrom:x:24:nikhil
floppy:x:25:
tape:x:26:
sudo:x:27:nikhil
audio:x:29:pulse
```

The first string (separated by :) specifies the group name and the last string specifies the user added to this group.