# how to list groups along with its users using terminal in ubuntu 14.04.5?

Tags: command-line, users, groups

For example: Group `workers` have 2 users: `john` and `jony` . What command do I have to use to list the members of group `workers` ?

These commands don't serve my purpose:  `compgen -u` , `compgen -g`, `cut -d ":" -f 1 /etc/passwd`

Comment: Does `groups <username>` from a terminal work?

Comment: yes its working :) Thank you so much :) :) :) Post it as an answer :)

Comment: I thought OP meant all users a particular group @Terrance?

Comment: @George Yes, you are correct.

Comment: Related:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/136788/how-do-i-list-the-members-of-a-group

Comment: @jabi in addition to Terrance link this could be helpful too `grep -iE "^adm" /etc/group | cut -d":" -f4-`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several options are available:

```
getent group <group_name> | cut -d":" -f4-
```

or

```
grep -iE "^adm" /etc/group | cut -d":" -f4-
```

Note you have to add the group name where I have `"^adm`, this will present members of that group.

See: `man getent`

Comment: If you know the (full) group name, then you can give it as a key to `getent` directly (avoiding the call to `grep`) e.g. `getent group workers`