# "getent" doesn't show members in the group

Tags: users, user-management, groups

If I command `id nu`, the output shows that the user `nu` belongs to the group named `nuu`.
But if check the members of the group `nuu` with the command `getent group nuu` it shows as if there are no members in this group.

```
# id nu
uid=1002(nu) gid=1003(nuu) groups=1003(nuu)
# getent group nuu
nuu:x:1003:
# members nuu
nu
```

To reconfirm, I downloaded another utility named `members` and then using this command, I could again confirm the group `nuu` does have `nu` as its member. Why this discrepancy though?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: Ok. I'll fully pay attention to this in future. Sorry for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

A user doesn't need to be listed as the member of their primary group in the `group` database because that relationship is defined in the user's `passwd` entry. Generally, only supplementary group memberships are listed in the `group` database. Your outputs are consistent with this.

Comment: I didn't fully understand, but got some idea. Your meaning is that this ubuntu command is designed this way and 'that command' won't show any group's primary members (but if the same group was someone's secondary group, then those members would've been returned/showed). If this is the case, can you pls tell if there is any other built-in/default ubuntu command, which would show all primary members of a group (command which is included in the ubuntu itself, i.e. we don't need to install any other packages for that command to work). 
Hope I was able to make myself clear.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You'll have to get all users, check their primary group, and then combine that with the memberships listed in `getent group`.